# I want fixed the Right Text ， Left Text using remaining space

Tags: flutter

I have two widget : Text A, Text B, Text A is very long text,
B is right , I want to fix B position and full visible, and let A widget using remaining space and new line to show B text.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('AAAAAAAAAAAA--------------------------------------------------------'),
              //Spacer(),
              Text(
                "BBBBBBBBB",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Color(0xFF666666)),
              )
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text(
              'AAAAAAAAAAAA---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')),
          //Spacer(),
          Text(
            "BBBBBBBBB",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Color(0xFF666666)),
          )
        ],
      )
```